# SharePoint Migration Tool no longer runs or installs

Tags: sharepoint, .net

I terminated the SharePoint Migration tool in task manager to change the working folder. but the tool no longer starts again. agentsetup.exe will also not run, so I am unable to re/install the app. Microsoft 365 Migration Agent is listed in Add/Remove Programs, but is not unistallable. We have looked through the registry, WMIC, DISM, and SFC. I tried to reinstall .NET 4.6.5, but it installed, and the .NET Repair Tool only was able to reregister and restart msiexec.exe, but the tools still fail.

First error when running agentsetup.exe, .NET Runtime, Event ID 1026:

```
    Application: Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(Newtonsoft.Json.ReadType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Boolean)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, System.String)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, System.Object)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, Boolean)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.String, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientLib.Common.AgentSettings.Load()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientLib.Common.AgentSettings.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.Common.InstallWizard.InitInstallWorker(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.PagesStructure.InitAllPages(Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.MainWindow)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.MainWindow..ctor()

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.App.Main()
```

Second error, Application Error, Event ID 1000:

```
Faulting application name: Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.exe, version: 1.1.0.32, time stamp: 0x64142ce5
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.2788, time stamp: 0x62e593d6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000002cb69
Faulting process id: 0x2360
Faulting application start time: 0x01d976c2b86ef13b
Faulting application path: \AppData\Local\Temp\SPMigrationAgentSetup\SPMigrationAgentSetup\Microsoft.SharePoint.Migration.ClientInstaller.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 60127fdb-c018-40c6-8c17-32ef7e6686c5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: did you cleanup any temp folders?

Comment: @djdomi We removed folders that agentsetup.exe made in appdata.

Comment: it looks for me that you are may having a issue with the net framework, verify the logs for it

Comment: @djdomi Even if I already tried the .net installer and repair tools?